# Zend Framework Custom form element gets repeated

Tags: zend-framework, forms, element, repeat

I've got a strange problem.

I created a custom form element. I created it with two select-form-elements to select a time (00:00).

The strange things is that when i use it once in a form its ok, but when i use it a second time (because an appointment has a beginning and an end time) the first one is shown again. So i end up with three times the form-element. When i use it again it shows the first two also and i end up with 6 times the form element.

Does anybody know how to prevent his from happening?

The Code:

Form Element

```
<?php

class App_Form_Element_TimeSelect extends Zend_Form_Element_Xhtml
{

    public $helper = 'FormTimeSelect';
    protected $hour = null;
    protected $minutes = null;

    public function setHour($hour)
    {
        $this->hour = $hour;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setMinutes($minutes)
    {
        $this->minutes = $minutes;
        return $this;
    }

    public function setValue($value)
    {
        if (is_array($value)
                && isset($value['hour'])
                && isset($value['minutes']))
        {
            $this->setHour($value['hour'])
                    ->setMinutes($value['minutes']);
        }
    }

    public function getValue()
    {
        if (!$this->hour || !$this->minutes)
            return false;
        return $this->hour . ':' . $this->minutes;
    }

}
```

The view Helper

```
<?php

class App_View_Helper_FormTimeSelect extends Zend_View_Helper_FormElement {

    protected $html = '';

    public function FormTimeSelect($name, $value = null, $attribs = null)
    {
        $hour = '00';
        $minute = '00';
        if ($value)
            list($hour, $minute) = split(':', $value);

        $helper = new Zend_View_Helper_FormSelect();
        $helper->setView($this->view);

        $hourarray = array('00' => '00', '01' => '01', '02' => '02', '03' => '03',
            '04' => '04', '05' => '05', '06' => '06', '07' => '07', '08' => '08',
            '09' => '09', '10' => '10', '11' => '11', '12' => '12', '13' => '13',
            '14' => '14', '15' => '15', '16' => '16', '17' => '17', '18' => '18',
            '19' => '19', '20' => '20', '21' => '21', '22' => '22', '23' => '23');
        $minutearray = array('00' => '00', '15' => '15', '30' => '30', '45' => '45');

        $this->html .= $helper->formSelect($name . '[hour]', $hour, null, $hourarray);
        $this->html .= ' : ';
        $this->html .= $helper->formSelect($name . '[minutes]', $minute, null, $minutearray);

        return $this->html;
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Peter

Comment: Try first without using the array notation here: ($name[hour]). It is not so handy with Zend_Form, you may need to use subforms to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior is normal. The reason is that when you call a helper from the view, it just executes formTimeSelect() method on an instance of `App_View_Helper_FormTimeSelect`. You need to remember that during Zend application execution, there is only one instance of the helper. Thus, in your code, calling the helper from the view multiple times will just append new html (result of `FormTimeSelect` method) to the existing string in a $html variable. If you call the method multiple times, you will see multiple version of the string. So just reset (`$html=''`) the value of $html at the beginning of `FormTimeSelect` method.

Hope this will clarify the problem.